# Php agrupate elements in array with explode

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I need explode different values, and at the same time, with differents delimiters, in this case "*" and ",", and i want group elements with the same element in common, in this case **"car1"**

With the example i try group elements with the same element when use explode, but don´t get finally

```
        <?php
/// Values to Explode
        $a="house1,car1,phone1*house2,car1,phone2*house3,car3,phone3*";
/// First Explode
        $exp_1=explode("*",$a);

/// Loop Explode with "*"
        foreach($exp_1 as $exps)
        {
        $exps=explode(",",$exps);

    /// Here i want group the arrays or elements contain the same - car1 -                in this case 1 and 2 arrays

    /// I try do this but don´t works ///

        if ($exps[1]==$exps[1])
        {
        /// Must show house1,car1,phone1 and house2,car1,phone2 because have the same car called car1, and group en each case, common element it´s car1
        print "ok";
        }
        else
        {
        print "Others";
        }

        }

        ?>
```

Comment: _agrupate_? Also, indentation and whitespace.

Comment: Don´t understand your comment

Comment: Agrupate isn't a word (in English, anyway) - I assume you mean aggregate, but it's not still really clear what you're trying to do. What do you want `if ($exps[1]==$exps[1])` to achieve - any PHP variable will obviously equal itself.

Comment: This it´s a example, i don´t know how get this result and by this put my question here

Comment: Anton, I understand your frustration, but at the same time you should try to understand the purpose and goals of Stack Overflow. Maybe you would be better off with a traditional forum.

Answer (score 0):

Use preg split:

```
$a = "house1,car1,phone1*house2,car1,phone2*house3,car3,phone3*";
$parts = preg_split('/[*|,]/', $a);
var_dump ($parts);
```

Comment: Thank´s i go to try