# Group same values in array using explode or similar method

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, explode

**I have this string :**

```
$a="house1,car1,phone1*house2,car2,phone2*house3,car1,phone3*house4,car3,phone3*";
```

And i want show in order, the house with the same car, as you can se the element that repeat it´s called "car1"

**I want get this :**

```
CAR 1 IN THIS HOUSE
    house1,car1,phone1
    house3,car1,phone3

CAR 2 AND  3 IN HOUSES 2 AND 4   
    house2,car2,phone2
    house4,car3,phone3
```

As you can see, the **car1** repeat in 2 houses with different name, and i want order results in this way

I try do this in many ways, use array_diff, array_unique in foreach loop with explode and array_intersect, and results very bad

If somebody can help me here, thank´s, because i don´t know how i can comparate and show results as i put until

**Thank´s in advanced and regards community**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php agrupate elements in array with explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47756708/php-agrupate-elements-in-array-with-explode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (tested in php 5.6):

```
<?php

// input string
$a="house1,car1,phone1*house2,car2,phone2*house3,car1,phone3*house4,car3,phone3*";

// split on '*' to get tuples
$tuples = explode('*', $a);

// ignore empty tuples (trailing '*' in input string)
$tuples = array_filter($tuples);

// split each tuple on ',' to get individual values
function splitTuples($tuple) {
    return explode(',', $tuple);
}
$tuples = array_map('splitTuples', $tuples);

// sort tuples by the 2nd value
function sortArraysBySecondValue($a, $b) {
    if ($a[1] < $b[1]) {
        return -1;
    }
    if ($a[1] > $b[1]) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
usort($tuples, 'sortArraysBySecondValue');

// print tuples
foreach ($tuples as $tuple) {
    echo implode(',', $tuple) . "\n";
}
```

Output is:

```
house1,car1,phone1
house3,car1,phone3
house2,car2,phone2
house4,car3,phone3
```

Comment: Give me error in line 13 more or less give this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')', regards and thank´s

Comment: I've updated my answer for older versions of php that can't use anonymous functions in usort

Comment: don´t understand but continue error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in tester.php on line 13

Comment: Which version of php are you using please?

Comment: I've updated the answer again, removing the anonymous function call from array_map